# How to find multiple route betveen two location using mkmapview

Tags: ios, objective-c, mkmapview

I need to display multiple route between two locations which are user entry location and also display a shortest route between them. The shortest route is one of the from multiple route.

please help in this.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

MKDirections calculateDirectionsWithCompletionHandler method, returns a MKDirectionsResponse object, which contains the array of possible MKRoutes as a property.

The following code gets all the routes between two locations, and then orders the array using NSSortDescriptor to get the array of routes ordered by their shortest distance.

Hope it helps!

```
//Create MKDirectionsRequest
MKDirectionsRequest * request = [[MKDirectionsRequest alloc] init];
request.source = [[MKMapItem alloc] initWithPlacemark:[[MKPlacemark alloc] initWithCoordinate:sourceCoordinate addressDictionary:nil]];
request.destination = [[MKMapItem alloc] initWithPlacemark:[[MKPlacemark alloc] initWithCoordinate:destinationCoordinate addressDictionary:nil]];
request.transportType = MKDirectionsTransportTypeAutomobile; //Or any other transport type.
//Get directions between two points
MKDirections * directions = [[MKDirections alloc] initWithRequest:request];
[directions calculateDirectionsWithCompletionHandler:^(MKDirectionsResponse *response, NSError *error) {
    NSSortDescriptor *sortDescriptor;
    sortDescriptor = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"distance"
                                             ascending:YES];
    //Get the routes array sorted by distance
    NSArray *sortDescriptors = [NSArray arrayWithObject:sortDescriptor];
    NSArray *sortedRoutes;
    sortedRoutes = [response.routes sortedArrayUsingDescriptors:sortDescriptors];

    //The fastest route is the one at index 0 of the sorted array
    MKRoute * fastestRoute = [sortedRoutes objectAtIndex:0];
 }];
```